# How to use OnDismiss in order to use dialog box input?

Tags: android, user-input, dialog

I have a dialog box prompt for the user and the user input is to be used in the next step of the code. I am trying to use OnDismiss to make the rest of the code take in user input. Below is the code snippet:

AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

```
    alert.setTitle("Title");
    alert.setMessage("Message");

    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

        input = 3;
      }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
          input = 1;
      }
    });

    alert.show();

    }

public void OnDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface)
{
Toast.makeText(this, "Input: " + input, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
.show();
```

}

However, when I press the dialog box button, the dialog box is dismissed but the toast does not appear. Please suggest what am I doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `OnDismissListener` to your `AlertDialog` first then call `dismiss()` when dialog button is pressed, code as bellowing:

```
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    alert.setTitle("Title");
    alert.setMessage("Message");

    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        input = 3;
        dialog.dismiss();
      }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
          input = 1;
          dialog.dismiss();
      }
    });

   alert.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener(){
       public void OnDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface)
         {
          Toast.makeText(this, "Input: " + input, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
         .show();
          }
   });

    alert.show();
```

Comment: perfect, thanks! worked like a charm. just that I had to mention MainActivity.this instead of just this in the toast; mentioning it for the benefit of others who may have the same issue. Thanks all for the great help :)

Answer (score 0):

you have to use  dialog.dismiss();

```
  alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

    input = 3;
   dialog.dismiss();
  }
});

  alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
      input = 1;
  dialog.dismiss();
  }
});
```